# Invoking powershell from Java

Tags: java, powershell, interop

Anyone know of a good library to invoke powershell scripts from within Java? I'm currently spawning a seperate process (powershell.exe) and then parse the output, but it would really be nice if I can leverage Powershell's 'power' by getting objects back from a powershell call.

Edit:

Otherwise, anyone else doing such interop? What method do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The downside to crossplatform tools is that you only have a common subset of tools for each platform - This is not possible through Java. You could do some JNI or use the method you have already tried

Answer (score 2):

After posting, I realized that this is not the answer to your question, but for anybody else who wants to call PowerShell from Java and is fine spinning up a separate process, here's how.

Assuming your Powershell script is in script.ps1, you can run it in a separate process using:

```
String cmd = "powershell C:\\path\\to\\your\\script\\script.ps1"
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runtime.exec(command);
process.getOutputStream().close();
```

Comment: he already is spawning a seperate process (powershell.exe) and then parses the output. He asked for specific java interaction between powershell and java.

Answer (score 0):

I've found [Powershell Bridge (PSB)](http://www.javaexchangeconnector.com/). Still need to look into it though

Comment: Prerequisites include "Exchange Powershell, or Exchange Management Shell2", which seems outside the scope of this question.